# How to use new layout editor for Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

New Eclipse layout editor for Android devices has a lot of new gui elements, is there are any tutorial on how to use it?

**Updated**: I was just trying to add HorizontalScrollView to layout, and don't see any feedback from a screen. Should I just use xml to edit layout, and use visual view just for verification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements can be found in the android.widget package, so I would recommend to head over to
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html
have a closer look at your GUI-element of choice and just try it out.

Or, alternatively google for example code snippets - I'm sure there is at least one for each element

Answer (score 1):

The editor itself is very self-descriptional, but detailed informations you can only get by offering more details of what you really want do.